# Delete value from array object in javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, splice

I am trying to delete objects from my array via javascript. Im building a simple mobile jquery application and want to delete items from an array. I use the following code. I have a list with checkboxes in it. Every checkbox has a value that belongs to the list item. So when multiple checkboxes are checked.. it should delete all these objects (items) from the array.

```
function deleteFunction()
    {
        objects = getObjects();
        $("input:checked").each(function()
        {
            var inputValue = $(this).val();
            for(i = getObjects().length; i >=0; i--)
            {

                if('{"title":"'+ inputValue + '"}' == JSON.stringify(objects[i]))
                {
                    objects.splice(i, 1);
                    return true;
                }
            }

        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(objects));
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

The annoying thing is as follows:
When i slice the object from the array, the object is restored on the second iteration. So it always removes only 1 object from the array.

To test my output i used the following code within the if statement:

```
alert(i);
alert(JSON.stringify(objects[i]));  
objects.splice(i, 1);
alert(i);
alert(JSON.stringify(objects)); 
return true;
```

The output is as follows

```
1
{"title":"hi2"}
1
[{"title":"hi1"}, {"title":"hi3"}]
2
{"title":"hi3"}
2
[{"title":"hi1"}, {"title":"hi2"}]
```

so i slice hi2, but has returned

Thanx for answer and respond

**Solution Thanx to depperm + indubitablee:**

```
function deleteFunction()
{
    var objects = getObjects();
    $("input:checked").each(function()
    {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        for(i = objects.length -1; i >=0; i--)
        {           
            if(objects[i].title == inputValue)
            {                               
                objects.splice(i, 1);           
            }
        }

    });
    localStorage.setItem("objects", JSON.stringify(objects));
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: remove/comment out the return true statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I would change, first in the `for` loop no need to call `getObjects()` each time just use `objects`. Then in the `if` simply check if the `objects[i].title` is the same as the `inputValue`.

```
function deleteFunction()
{
    objects = getObjects();
    $("input:checked").each(function()
    {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        for(i = objects .length; i >=0; i--)
        {
            if(objects[i].title==inputValue)
            {
                objects.splice(i, 1);                     
            }
        }

    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(objects));
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: i changed slice into splice :D messed my code a lot last hours :D

Comment: thanx.. this was the solution      

i add it also beneath my main post

Answer (score 0):

use `.splice()` instead of `.slice()`.

`slice` does NOT alter/manipulate the original array at all, it just creates another array based on your selection.

`splice` does alter the original array.

reference: http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/slice-and-splice-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

The array method `slice` does not remove array elements. Use `splice` instead.

There are some problems with your code:

1. You missed the keyword `var` sometimes.
2. The variable `i` is equal to the length of the array in the first iteration. It should be one minus that.
3. Instead of converting to JSON to compare the objects, you could have just compared the value of the title property.